# Difference between 'tips on study' and 'tips at study'?

Tags: vocabulary

I am confused between

> Today i would like to give you tips on study

and

> Today i would like to give you tips at study

Can anyone explain which one should i use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tips on** is what is more commonly said in the US in my opinion.

> Can anyone give me some **tips on** how to study English more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what phrase is idiomatically the most common, it wouldn't be either of them.

The most common would be:

> Today, I would like to give you **study tips**.

You could also use:

> Today, I would like to give you tips **on** ***how to*** study.
>   Today, I would like to give you tips **on** ***studying***.

At least in terms of writing, you can see this from [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tips+on+study%2Ctips+at+study%2C+study+tips%2Ctips+on+studying%2Ctips+at+studying%2Ctips+on+how+to+study%2Ctips+at+how&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctips%20on%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStudy%20Tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSTUDY%20TIPS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctips%20on%20studying%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btips%20on%20studying%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTips%20on%20Studying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctips%20on%20how%20to%20study%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctips%20on%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStudy%20Tips%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSTUDY%20TIPS%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStudy%20tips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctips%20on%20studying%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btips%20on%20studying%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTips%20on%20Studying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctips%20on%20how%20to%20study%3B%2Cc0):

[image: study tips]

Notice the frequency of the variations, and the fact that where a preposition is used, it's *on*, not *at*. (And I actually queried *tips at how*, not just *tips at how to study*, and got no hits for anything.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford's advanced learner's dictionary
**tips on sth/tips for sth/tips for/on doing sth** are acceptable